# How to change the permissions on a HDFS folder created by impala

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, impala

How to change the permissions on the HDFS folder created by impala? I have a set of statements that would partition an HDFS directory and load data into it.

I'm executing this statement in imapala-shell thru `impala -f` option (I append all the statements to a file and then run it). Everything is getting created with permissions `drwxr-x---`. Does anyone know how to change that?

Comment: *[sigh]* Just use the HDFS command-line interface! `hdfs dfs -help` will list the equivalent of many "classical" filesystem commands -- i.e. `-ls`, `-chmod`, `-chown`, `-setfacl` etc. etc.

Comment: If you want to change the *default* privileges for directories & files created by Hive / Impala / Pig / whatever, then you will have to tinker with the HDFS `umask` property -- and/or set default ACLs on the parent directory *(but beware of the nasty bug about ACL propagation that will not be solved before Hadoop 3.0)*